# Boolean or remesh sharp either does not create a single object or simple destroys my object

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing, remesh

I've created a design of a fence panel which has a company name and contact info I want to 3D print. Problem I’m having is remeshing or combining all the parts. Boolean or remesh sharp just seems to either not create a single object or simple destroys my object. I've remeshed each part and made them manifold and to scale. How can I resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe share your file so that we can understand what's happening?

Comment: Need to see the .blend file I think, but if you put it into the 3D slicing software like Ultimaker it may just work anyway, in my experience it's been quite forgiving of a little dodgy geometry here and there.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response I’ll upload in a jiffy. I’m using Bambu lab software but will try ultimaker. The thing with bambu lab painting surfaces for printing, edges and flat surfaces are a must otherwise I’m trying to paint a billion faces.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=pMBAAZj1" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/pMBAAZj1/)

Comment: thanks for the help I've made stuff before but always used the voxel remesh

Answer (score 1):

Select all objects, press ctrl-J to join to one mesh, then remesh modifier like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for the help.  That’s what I tried but I’m getting the weird breaks and distortions like the gaps at the bottom and the slot on the right side those are not meant to be there I was also getting breaks in the mesh at the top.